# Format a JavaScript object placeholders and an object of substitutions

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object with placeholder ${var_name}

```
{
  "name": "${title}",
  "description": "${description}",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "Organization"
  },
  "hasInstance": [
    {
      "@type": "instance",
      "mode": [
        "study",
        "online"
      ],
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "price": "${price}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And an object of substitutions

```
{
  "title": "aaa",
  "description": "bbb \n ccc",
  "price": 100,
  "history": "ddd"
}
```

After replace the placeholders, the expected result:

```
{
  "name": "aaa",
  "description": "bbb \n cc",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "Organization"
  },
  "hasInstance": [
    {
      "@type": "instance",
      "mode": [
        "study",
        "online"
      ],
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "price": 100
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

my function with the idea:

- convert the object with placeholders to string
- then replace with object of substitutions
- convert string to object again

The problem is: `JSON.parse` will be failed with data contains JSON escape such as: ", \, /, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t

```
function replace(template, data) {
    let templateString = JSON.stringify(template);
    var placeholders = templateString.match(/\${([\w\.\:]+)}/g);

    placeholders.forEach(placeholder => {
        // convert ${var_name} to var_name, then assign to phText
        let phText = placeholder.substring(2,placeholder.length - 1);
        if(data[phText]) {
            templateString = templateString.replace(placeholder, data[phText]);
        }
    });

    return JSON.parse(templateString);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without JSON parsing, scan the object recursively, search for the placeholder pattern, and replace it with the new value:

```
function scanObjectAndReplace(newValues, obj, key=false){
    if(key && typeof(obj[key])==='string'){
        let str = obj[key];
        let i1=str.indexOf("${"); 
        let i2=str.indexOf("}");
        if(i1>=0 && i2>i1) {
            let keyname = str.substring(i1+2, i2);
            let substr = str.substring(i1, i2+1);
            if(!(keyname in newValues)) {console.log(`key ${keyname} not exist in new valuse.`);return}
            if(i1==0 && i2==str.length-1) // if value include only the placeholder then set a new value
                obj[key] = newValues[keyname];
            else
                obj[key] = str.replace(substr,values[keyname]); // otherwise treat it as string replacment
            console.log(`oldval=${str}, newval=${obj[key]}, type=${typeof(obj[key])}`)
        }
    } else {
        let objval = key ? obj[key] : obj;
        if (Object.keys(Object(objval)).length>0) {
            for (const k of Object.keys(objval)){
                console.log(k);
                scanObjectAndReplace(newValues,objval, k);
            }
        }
    }
}
scanObjectAndReplace(new_values, obj); // call the function
```

You can use regexp for a shorter version, but my function is easier to debug.

Answer (score -1):

Your code works, just

> ```
> "description": "bbb \n ccc"
> ```

should be

```
"description": "bbb \\n ccc"
```

in the code because you are working with the JSON string, where these control characters are escaped, so it has to be a backslash `\` and the `n`, and to get a backslash in code, you have to write two, as usual:

```js
function replace(template, data) {
  let templateString = JSON.stringify(template);
  var placeholders = templateString.match(/\${([\w\.\:]+)}/g);

  placeholders.forEach(placeholder => {
    // convert ${var_name} to var_name, then assign to phText
    let phText = placeholder.substring(2, placeholder.length - 1);
    if (data[phText]) {
      templateString = templateString.replace(placeholder, data[phText]);
    }
  });

  return JSON.parse(templateString);
}

let test=replace({
  "name": "${title}",
  "description": "${description}",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "Organization"
  },
  "hasInstance": [{
    "@type": "instance",
    "mode": [
      "study",
      "online"
    ],
    "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "price": "${price}"
    }
  }]
}, {
  "title": "aaa",
  "description": "bbb \\n ccc",       // <-- here
  "price": 100,
  "history": "ddd"
});
console.log(test);
console.log(test.description);
```

As the `console.log()` of an object may look fishy, added a log of the given field too, it does have a working linebreak inside.

---

> I knew the rootcause, but I don't want to change the input

That's great, then alternatively you can just escape it prior to the replacement. One way to do that is `JSON.stringify()` itself, it does the escaping exactly as it's expected for JSON, the only inconvenience is that it also wraps a string with quotation marks, which then have to be removed.

```js
function replace(template, data) {
  let templateString = JSON.stringify(template);
  var placeholders = templateString.match(/\${([\w\.\:]+)}/g);

  placeholders.forEach(placeholder => {
    // convert ${var_name} to var_name, then assign to phText
    let phText = placeholder.substring(2, placeholder.length - 1);
    let rpText = data[phText];
    if (rpText) {
      rpText = JSON.stringify(rpText);             // <-- here
      rpText = rpText.substr(1,rpText.length-2);   // <-- and here
      templateString = templateString.replace(placeholder, rpText);
    }
  });

  return JSON.parse(templateString);
}

let test=replace({
  "name": "${title}",
  "description": "${description}",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "Organization"
  },
  "hasInstance": [{
    "@type": "instance",
    "mode": [
      "study",
      "online"
    ],
    "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "price": "${price}"
    }
  }]
}, {
  "title": "aaa",
  "description": "bbb \n ccc",       // <-- and not here
  "price": 100,
  "history": "ddd"
});
console.log(test);
console.log(test.description);
```

Comment: I knew the rootcause, but I don't want to change the input

Comment: @VuLeAnh ok, see second snippet then.